# How is this equation derived from the following information?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I am doing a lab in seismic ray tracing and I am trying to understand how the following equation is derived: $$ \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\theta}\left( \dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{ \text{d} r}{ \text{d}  \theta } \right) =  \left(  \dfrac{ r }{ pv }  \right)^2 \left( 1- \dfrac{ r }{ v }  \dfrac{  \text{d} v }{  \text{d} r }  \right)  $$

Apparently, this is found by taking the derivative with respect to $\theta$ of this equation: $$ \left(  \dfrac{ r }{ pv }  \right)^2 = 1+ \left(  \dfrac{ 1 }{ r } \dfrac{  \text{d} r }{ \text{d}  \theta   }   \right)^2  $$

where the ray parameter $p = \dfrac{r_k\sin(i)_k}{v_k} = \text{constant} \hspace{7px}$ for any $k$.

Here is a diagram that shows the problem:

[image]

The $v_k$'s are the velocities of the propagating ray/wave through the material.

Comment: What is the problem? Is there any specific difficulty with differentiating by $\theta$?

Comment: Yes, I am just completely lost. I am unsure where to start and whether or not the chain rule is being used here etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Let us differentiate the second equation with respect to $\theta$ :

$$\frac{d}{d\theta} (\frac{r}{pv})^2 = \frac{d}{d\theta} (1 + (\frac{1}{r} \frac{dr}{d\theta})^2)$$
$$\implies \frac{r}{pv}\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{r}{pv}) = \frac{1}{r} \frac{dr}{d\theta} \frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{1}{r}\frac{dr}{d\theta})$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{r}\frac{dr}{d\theta} \frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{1}{r}\frac{dr}{d\theta}) = \frac{r}{pv}\frac{1}{p} \frac{1}{v^2}(v \frac{dr}{d\theta} - r \frac{dv}{d\theta})$$
$$\implies \frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{1}{r} \frac{dr}{d\theta}) = (\frac{r}{pv})^2 (1 - \frac{r}{v}\frac{dv}{dr})$$